# Retrieve percentile of a specific value in SQL column

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's say I know I have a specific value in an SQL column, and I want to determine its percentile. Based on another SO post (https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/13703/get-the-rank-of-a-user-in-a-score-table) I tried to modify this, which works but returns the rank of every value in the column:

```
mysql> SELECT FIND_IN_SET( sum_squares, (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(sum_squares ORDER BY sum_squares DESC)                  |
    -> FROM entries)                                                                                                 |
    -> ) AS rank                                                                                                     |
    -> FROM entries;
```

As below:

```
+------+                                                                                                             |
| rank |                                                                                                             |
+------+                                                                                                             |
|    4 |                                                                                                             |
|    4 |                                                                                                             |
|    2 |                                                                                                             |
|    3 |                                                                                                             |
|    1 |                                                                                                             |
+------+
```

I tried to modify it by appending a `WHERE` statement before the `FROM entries` as below:

```
mysql> SELECT FIND_IN_SET( sum_squares, (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(sum_squares ORDER BY sum_squares DESC)                  |
    -> FROM entries)                                                                                                 |
    -> ) AS rank          
    -> ) WHERE sum_squares = 5                                                                                             |
    -> FROM entries;
```

This leads to the following error:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE sum_squares = 5
FROM entries' at line 4
```

Can someone explain to me why my query seems to be disallowed and if there is another way to do this? I'd rather not return the entire column!

Here's a sample `entries` table:

```
+----+-------------+
| id | sum_squares |
+----+-------------+
|  1 |           5 |
|  2 |           5 |
|  3 |          55 |
|  4 |          33 |
|  5 |         111 |
+----+-------------+
```

Comment: Use a `having` clause rather than a `where` clause.  This is a MySQL extension that does what you want.  Plus, you need to put it in the right place in the select statement.

Comment: @GordonLinoff that did it. I can post the answer (put the HAVING after the first FROM entries)  if you don't want to. let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what *almost* did it following @GordonLinoff's comment:

```
mysql> SELECT FIND_IN_SET( sum_squares, (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( sum_squares ORDER BY sum_squares DESC)
    -> FROM entries HAVING sum_squares = 5)
    -> )  AS rank
    -> FROM entries
```

However this returns the answer in matching rows plus NULL in other rows, so I'd welcome improvements on this. Thanks.

```
+------+
| rank |
+------+
|    4 |
|    4 |
| NULL |
| NULL |
| NULL |
+------+
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the rank for a single entry, try this query:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT sum_squares) + 1
FROM entries
WHERE sum_squares > 5 ;
```